# connect to SMTP using Oauth2 Gmail

Tags: smtp, gmail, google-oauth

I am trying to connect SMTP using the Oauth2 for Gmail , but getting the following issues.

**Oauth token and email name** are correct and works to connect IMAP.

I am following the [example of google](http://code.google.com/p/google-mail-oauth2-tools/source/browse/trunk/java/com/google/code/samples/oauth2/OAuth2Authenticator.java?r=3).

```
DEBUG SMTP: Authenticate with SASL
DEBUG SMTP: SASL mechanisms allowed: XOAUTH2
DEBUG SMTP: SASL AUTH command trace suppressed
DEBUG SMTP SASL: Mechanisms: XOAUTH2
DEBUG SMTP SASL: No SASL support
DEBUG SMTP: SASL authentication failed
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate
DEBUG SMTP: check mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM 
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN failed


javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.1 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 ol4sm17455809pbb.58
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just forget to call the initialize () method of OAuth2Authenticator class.

```
 public static void initialize() {
    Security.addProvider(new OAuth2Provider());
  }
```

Comment: Can you please mark the question as answered, if adding the initialize() method indeed solved your problem? Thanks.